# Chrome CSS Hack Not working in Print Preview

Tags: css, google-chrome, print-preview

I have an alignment issue only in Chrome and am using the following Chrome CSS hack in my print.css: 
    @media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0){
        .invoiceTable .smallerInput{
        margin-top:9px !important;
        }
    }

When I go to print preview, the style has not been applied.
If I add the Chrome only CSS hack into the normal page view CSS, I can see that the styles are applied correctly in Chrome and not affected in other browsers. Seems like it isn't detected for the print preview for some reason.
Does anyone know how to get it to work on the print preview for Chrome?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use 
        `@media print`
to target a printer.

Comment: Yes, I have the stylesheets setup correctly:
    <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' media="screen" href='/stylesheets/invoice.css' />
     <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' media="print" href='/stylesheets/invoicePrint.css' />
but it is still not working for the print preview

Comment: Your media querie says '@media screen'. A printer is not a screen.

Comment: That CSS file with the media="screen" (/stylesheets/invoice.css) is for the normal web view. The 2nd one with the media="print" (/stylesheets/invoicePrint.css) is for the print view which contains the Chrome only CSS mentioned above and is not being applied.

Comment: I understand that. I'm saying that in your print.css file you have '@media screen...'  This only works on screens. You need to change it to '@media print...'  as you are trying to target a printer not a screen.

Comment: Ahh, sorry about my misunderstanding. You are talking about the actual Chrome hack code. It works perfectly now. Thanks!

Comment: Some one can help me i m using media="print" only is not coming in chrome but its working in firefox and IE10

Comment: @Dinesh You should open a new question so that we can see your code.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23514500/media-print-is-not-working-in-google-chrome

Comment: Yes see this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23514500/media-print-is-not-working-in-google-chrome

Answer (score 1):

Use link tag

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="my-sample-print-style.css" media="print"/>
```